# Piling up a vector and multiplying by a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, analysis, matrix-calculus

Let $V$ be a complex inner product space. Suppose $V$ is the orthogonal direct sum $V = U\oplus W$ of two of vector subspaces $U$ and $W$. Suppose further that $\text{dim}U = \text{dim}V = n$, $\{e_{1},...,e_{n}\}$ is a basis for $U$ and $\{f_{1},...,f_{n}\}$ is a basis for $W$.

Note that $V$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}^{2n}$. If $v = u + w$, $u \in U$ and $w \in W$, then write:
$$v = \sum_{i=1}^{n}(\alpha_{i}e_{i}+\beta_{i}f_{i}),$$
with $\alpha_{i},\beta_{i}\in \mathbb{C}$. Then one can send $v$ to a vector:
$$v \mapsto \begin{pmatrix}
\alpha_{1} \\
\beta_{1} \\
\alpha_{2}\\
\beta_{2} \\
\vdots \\
\alpha_{n} \\
\beta_{n}
\end{pmatrix}
\tag{1}\label{1}$$
that is, I am piling up the vectors $\binom{\alpha_{i}}{\beta_{i}}$, $i=1,...,n$.

Let us write:
$$v = \begin{pmatrix}
u \\
v
\end{pmatrix}
$$
as a column vector. Using this representation, let $A: W \to U$ be the following operator:
$$A = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & I \\
0 & 0
,\end{pmatrix}
$$
where $I$ is the identity map in $V$.

My question is: if $v$ is mapped to the piled vector as in (\ref{1}), then it seems that $A$ is mapped to:
$$A = \bigoplus_{i=1}^{n}\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
0 & 0
.\end{pmatrix}
$$
Is this true?